# Problem in launching Flutter project and not finding the answer

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm getting an error running Flutter projects
I also installed all the tools ... !
But they still get an error
How do I solve this problem?

Error screenshot !:
[image]

Thank you :)

Comment: Show in finder -> right mouse click -> open with or open. (try these steps twice, then an option to open anyways will appear)

Answer (score 0):

This thing maybe happens if you don't have a provisioning profile added.

you can solve this by just following the steps and you can install the app on your device.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]